# Row number related

Tags: sql

I have this type of table.

```
no    CustID             Amount
1     1234               1000
2     2345                500
3     1234               1000
4     6789                500
5     1234               1000
6     6789                350
7     2345                600    
8     1234                250
```

I need output like this

```
No    CustId             Amount
1     1234               1000
2     1234               1000
3     1234               1000
4     1234                250
1     2345                500
2     2345                600
1     6789                500
2     6789                350
```

Please give the Sql for this

Comment: I assume you have mixed up row 5 and 6 in the expected output. Also you should work a bit more on your questions. Include information about RDBMS and version. Explain what you are trying to do. What have you tried already.

Comment: Works in MySQL: You may have `AUTO_INCREMENT()` set on the `No`-column, and use `PRIMARY_KEY(No,CustId)`. This will automatically create unique numbers for each client and store them in the table, like your output is. You will in that case need to re-insert your data without the `No`-column set.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by CustId order by Amount desc) No, 
CustId, Amount
FROM <table>
ORDER BY CustId, Amount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As row numbers are to be assigned based on customer id's in groups following query will work in T-SQL:

```
select ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by CustID order by Amount desc) as [No],CustID,Amount
from table1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from TABLE_NAME order by CustId;
```